# Transmit Monitor Screen without using Software

Tags: windows, windows-7, screen-resolution, video, monitors

Is there anyway I can share my monitor screen to another monitor without any application/process running on my computer and only by using hardware/cables ,etc. I do not want to have 2 monitors connected either since it would show on the Screen Resolution in Win 7. Unless there is a way to hide that so it only shows 1 monitor. And I mean hide it without using any software....

Comment: Why does it matter what the OS is, when you insist on a hardware-only solution?

Answer (score 1):

Sure - depending on what type of cable/monitors you're using, splitters can be easily purchased. Some are active, some passive, depending on protocol and feature set.

Comment: Thank you. But wouldnt a spliter like https://www.google.com/shopping/product/13543802842113360673?q=monitor+cable+splitter&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=979&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&ion=1&bvm=pv.xjs.s.en_US.8Rnrv8-hPjQ.O&tch=1&ech=1&psi=vvIYVOHaMZHeoATsmIDYBQ.1410921288285.3&ei=WfMYVI3IDNjnoATyjIHQCw&ved=0CKoEEKYrMAA would show up on the "Screen Resolution" in windows 7 as additional monitor?

Comment: No it would not.